# OpenGL: in-GPU texture to texture copy

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, gpu

I want to copy parts of one texture that is already in video memory to a subregion of another texture that is also already in video memory. Fast. Without going through CPU side memory.

That's the way I try to do it:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, src_texId, 0);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dst_texId);
glCopyTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, dst_x, dst_y, src_x, src_y, width, height);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

the code compiles, and my destination texture does receive an update, but it does not seem to work correctly as it is updated with blueish junk data. Is my approach wrong?

Comment: This basically looks ok to me. I figure you have a valid FBO bound to `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER` when this code is executed? Another option is that you use `glBlitFramebuffer()` with both textures attached to an FBO. But what you're trying should work just as well.

Comment: How can I be sure that a valid FBO is bound to GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER? Probably that's the problem

Comment: calling glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER); right before these commands returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE, so I assume it is valid?

Comment: What are the internal texture formats for src_texId and dst_texId?